# batch script to store the filename,date modified and the file size of a specific directory into a .csv is resulting in a syntax error

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I  need to loop a set of files along a particular directory and store their filename,date modified and filesize into a  .csv file.the below code is giving me syntax errors. Kindly help on the below:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set baseDIR=%1 
cd %baseDIR% 
FOR /R %%a IN (*) DO 
    "%%a","%%~ta","%%za" >>test.csv
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: There is a superfluous line break following the `DO` and a missing tilde in `%%~za`

Comment: ...and there is an `echo` command missing...

Answer (score 1):

May be an idea to

```
ECHO "%%a","%%~ta","%%za" >>test.csv
```

without the `echo`, batch will attempt to execute `"%%a","%%~ta","%%za" >>test.csv`

Comment: Hi but the script does not not print the date modified,size etc content in the csv,rather prints some literals.Any idea how to populate filename,daetmodified & size  of files along a specific directory (using for loop)into the csv.I tried giving the following,it did not work though. 
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set baseDIR=%1
cd %baseDIR%
FOR /R D:\TESTING %%A IN (*) DO (ECHO "%%A","%%~tA","%%~zA" >>test.csv)
exit /b %errorlevel%

Answer (score 0):

This batch inserts a header and overwrites the output file:

```
@Echo off
setlocal
set "baseDIR=%~1" 
cd /D "%baseDIR%"
( Echo "filename","dateModified","filesize"
  FOR /R %%a IN (*) DO "%%a","%%~ta","%%za"
) >test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also something like that :

```bat
@echo off
Set "MasterFolder=%temp%"
Set "OuptFile=Test.csv"
If exist "%OuptFile%" Del "%OuptFile%"
Call :Test "%MasterFolder%" "%OuptFile%"
Start "" "%OuptFile%"
Exit 
::**************************************************
:Test <baseDIR> <OuptFile>
set baseDIR=%1 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A /S %baseDIR%') do (
   echo "%%a","%%~ta","%%~za" >> %2
)
exit /b %errorlevel%
::**************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Refining earlier answers here, below is a working script. Save the following to a file named `CSVDir.cmd`:

```cmd
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
IF /I "%1" == "/R" SET RECURSE=/R
IF /I "%1" == "/R" SHIFT
IF NOT "%1" == "" cd /D "%1"
( 
    ECHO filename,dateModified,filesize
    FOR %RECURSE% %%a IN (*) DO ECHO "%%a","%%~ta",%%~za
)
```

**Usage examples**:

`CSVDir` -- non-recursive CSV listing of current directory

`CSVDir /r` -- recursive CSV listing of current directory

`CSVDir C:\Some\Folder\Path` -- non-recursive CSV listing of *C:\Some\Folder\Path*

`CSVDir /R C:\Some\Folder\Path` -- recursive CSV listing of *C:\Some\Folder\Path*

**NOTE** that without the `/R` flag, it will list "bare" filenames, without their full path. Otherwise all filenames are listed with their full path.